What does 「キャビ」 mean?
In the song Bloom by Necry Talkie, the very first lyric is:

なんだかキャビの匂いがしてるガレージで

I believe it translates into something like "In the garage that smells like some kind of キャビ".
I don't know what キャビ means and I can't seem to find a definition in any japanese dictionaries. I assume that it might be slang for something, but the only answer I could find was that it's short for キャビネット, which doesn't sound right given the context of the lyric.

The lyrics of this song contain several pieces of guitar-related jargon (フレット, ビッグマフ, ファズ), so I think キャビ is one of those. Musicians use キャビ(ネット) in this sense.

アンプ部とスピーカー部が分離しているスタック型のギター/ベースアンプの、スピーカー部を指す言葉である。

